# Windows 7 command to add a leading zero to a batch of filenames

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch-rename

Having trouble getting the correct command syntax. We need to add a leading zero to a batch of files in a directory on a regular basis. I cannot download and install a software item to do so. The operating system is Windows-7. The length of the filenames varies. i.e. 000165-CityName1.pdf to 0000165-CityName1.pdf 000166-CityNameLonger2.pdf to 0000166-CityNameLonger2.pdf etc. Looking for a rename command that would work, can someone please suggest one, it would be appreciated. I have tried a half dozen without success.

Comment: Windows 7 does not rely on MS-DOS at all. MS-DOS doesn't support file names longer than 8+3 characters. Do you mean the Windows 7 command prompt?

Comment: Yes, I mean the Windows 7 command prompt.

Answer (score 4):

This powershell script should work just fine to add a 0 to the beginning of each filename in a folder. Save this script as a .ps1.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\temp\cityfiles\" | 
  Rename-Item -NewName {$_.BaseName.insert(0,'0') + $_.Extension}
```

This takes every file inside the folder cityfiles and adds a '0' to the beginning of each filename.

Comment: This worked!   I was un-aware of the "Powershell" normal command prompt failed using the code. Thank you.

Comment: @Techexpressinc Would you mind marking it as the answer for future users to search on? Glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 2):

#### How do I add a leading zero to a batch of filenames?

Use the following command:

```
for /f %f in ('dir /b *.pdf') do ren "%f" "0%f"
```

To use in a batch file replace `%` with `%%`:

```
for /f %%f in ('dir /b *.pdf') do ren "%%f" "0%%f"
```

Example usage:

```
F:\test\test>dir
 Volume in drive F is Expansion
 Volume Serial Number is 3656-BB63

 Directory of F:\test\test

24/06/2016  21:39    <DIR>          .
24/06/2016  21:39    <DIR>          ..
24/06/2016  21:38                 0 000165-CityName1.pdf
24/06/2016  21:38                 0 000166-CityNameLonger2.pdf
               2 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  1,769,011,425,280 bytes free

F:\test\test>for /f %f in ('dir /b *.pdf') do ren "%f" "0%f"

F:\test\test>ren "000165-CityName1.pdf" "0000165-CityName1.pdf"

F:\test\test>ren "000166-CityNameLonger2.pdf" "0000166-CityNameLonger2.pdf"

F:\test\test>dir
 Volume in drive F is Expansion
 Volume Serial Number is 3656-BB63

 Directory of F:\test\test

24/06/2016  21:40    <DIR>          .
24/06/2016  21:40    <DIR>          ..
24/06/2016  21:38                 0 0000165-CityName1.pdf
24/06/2016  21:38                 0 0000166-CityNameLonger2.pdf
               2 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  1,769,011,425,280 bytes free
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [dir](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) - Display a list of files and subfolders.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [ren](http://ss64.com/nt/ren.html) - Rename a file or files.

Answer (score 0):

While you could put this in a bat file and put some options and checking,
going to a cmd prompt and cd to the folder you want

- ren *.pdf 0*.pdf

Will add a zero in front of the name for any pdf

Comment: This did not work, I changed saved it as a bat file and click on it and the files with 4 leading zeroes stayed the same.

Comment: there is * or shift 8 that is not displaying, not sure why - It is ren *.pdf 0*.pdf

Comment: You have to preface code with 4 spaces. Or surround it with backticks. Stars have a special meaning in markdown.